# convert PowerShell output to DataGrid in WPF

Tags: wpf, powershell, datagrid, grid

I'm a beginner in WPF and would like to transform my PS script in a GUI

I was possible to do this with a textblock but it seems a bit messy and therefore I want to use a DataGrid to have more structured view. I'm a bit stuck and I've searched everywhere to find a solution but I couldn't find one that suits for me.

I've tried to do this with the following:

```
foreach ($Property in $agfCustom){
$DataGridView1.Rows.Add.($Property)   
}
```

I don't want any headers just rows and 2 columns with data in it.

full script below:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------#
#----Initial Declarations-------------------------------------#
#-------------------------------------------------------------#

Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore, PresentationFramework

$Xaml = @"
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Width="800" Height="400">
<Grid>
 <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="266.17498779296875,29.987503051757812,0,0" Name="leznbuixc7f7z"/>

<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="23" Width="120" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="42.17498779296875,33.1875,0,0" Name="userName"/>
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="326" Height="211" Margin="375.17498779296875,103.1875,0,0" Name="DataGridView1"/>
</Grid></Window>
"@

#-------------------------------------------------------------#
#----Control Event Handlers-----------------------------------#
#-------------------------------------------------------------#


#region section
function OnClick {
    


    # search for hostname assigned to user
$Computernames = Get-Content -Path "\\data\PC.csv" |    
                     Select-Object -Skip 3 |       
                     ConvertFrom-Csv  -Delimiter ","

$pcNamecsv        = $Computernames.Where({ $_."Details_Table0_User_Name0" -eq $userName.Text})."Details_Table0_Name0" | Where { $_ -like 'BNL0*' -or $_ -like 'BNL5*'}



$ADcomputing = @(
 'Name'
 'LastLogonDate'
 )

$ADproperty    = foreach ($PC in $pcNamecsv)
             {Get-ADcomputer $PC -Properties $ADcomputing} 

$pcName = ($ADproperty | Sort LastLogonDate -Descending | Select -First 1).Name

    # find properties in AD 
$agfProperties = @(
        'Name'
        'mail'
        'OfficePhone'
        'Description'
        'PasswordLastSet'
        'LastBadPasswordAttempt'
        'LockedOut'
        'Enabled'
        'msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed'
        'Givenname'
    )
$agfUser = Get-Aduser -Identity $userName.Text -Properties $agfProperties

$agfExpiry = Get-ADUser -identity $userName.Text –Properties  "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" |
                Select-Object -Property @{Name="ExpiryDate";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}} | 
                select -expandproperty "ExpiryDate" -first 1 
                  
  # Create CO

  $agfCustom =
[pscustomobject]@{   UserID                      = $agfUser.Name
                     Mail                        = $agfUser.mail
                     Phone                       = $agfUser.OfficePhone
                     Hostname                    = $pcName
                     LockedStatusAGF             = $agfUser.LockedOut
                     AccountEnabledAGF           = $agfUser.Enabled
                     LastBadPasswordAttemptAGF   = $agfUser.LastBadPasswordAttempt
                     PasswordExpiresAGF          = $agfExpiry
                     PasswordLastSetAGF          = $agfUser.PasswordLastSet

}


foreach ($Property in $agfCustom){
$DataGridView1.Rows.Add.($Property)   
}

}
#endregion 


#-------------------------------------------------------------#
#----Script Execution-----------------------------------------#
#-------------------------------------------------------------#

$Window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Parse($Xaml)

[xml]$xml = $Xaml

$xml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | ForEach-Object { Set-Variable -Name $_.Name -Value $Window.FindName($_.Name) }


$leznbuixc7f7z.Add_Click({OnClick $this $_})

$Window.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Did you try `DataGridView1.Items.Add($Property) `?

Comment: @mm8 I tried but I'm getting following error: Exception calling "ShowDialog" with "0" argument(s): "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key"
At line:101 char:1
+ $Window.ShowDialog()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$DataGridView1.AddChild` or `$DataGridView1.Items.Add` can be used to add an individual item to the `DataGrid` but if you want the columns to be auto-generated, you should use an `ItemsSource`.

Here is a working example:

```
$Xaml = @"
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Width="800" Height="400">
<StackPanel>
<DataGrid Name="DataGridView1" />
</StackPanel></Window>
"@


$Window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Parse($Xaml)

[xml]$xml = $Xaml

$xml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | ForEach-Object { Set-Variable -Name $_.Name -Value $Window.FindName($_.Name) }

$items = @(
  [pscustomobject]@{Id=1;Name='NameA'}
  [pscustomobject]@{Id=2;Name='NameB'}
)

$DataGridView1.ItemsSource = $items

$Window.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: It works, thanks!  But I'm seeing an empyty column on the right side when the output, like a mail address is smaller.. Is there a way I can autosize this? I've tried to hide the grid lines but if you scroll over it you still see the 3th column..

Comment: You could remove the empty column by setting the `HorizontalAlignment` prperty to `Left`: `<DataGrid Name="DataGridView1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />`

Comment: the horizontalAlignment is already "Left"?

Comment: it seems that it  wasn't on "Left". Thank you for your clear answers to my questions! :)